# using php output in the javascript variable gives Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

In index.php i have php code to convert mysql data to json format ..and i used html to use the php output in the javascript variable for d3..when i used the php file like below method

```
        d3.json("index.php", function(error, flare) {
          if (error) throw error;
            //d3 codes here....
            });
```

it works fine..but i want to give the php output to the javascript variable ..and i run the index.php like that...it gives

```
        Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

here

```
       root.children.forEach(function (child) {
                    collapse(child);
                });
```

index.php

```
                    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin321","php");       

                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())                
                      {
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                      }
                    $r = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM phpp");
                            $data = array();
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                             $data[] = $row;
                             }  
            function buildtree($src_arr, $parent_id = 0, $tree = array())
                    {
                        foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row)
                        {
                            if($row['parent'] == $parent_id)
                            {
                                foreach($row as $k => $v)
                                    $tree[$row['id']][$k] = $v;
                                unset($src_arr[$idx]);
        $tree[$row['id']]['children'] = buildtree($src_arr, $row['id']);
                            }
                        }
                        ksort($tree);
                        return $tree;
                    }

                    function insertIntoNestedArray(&$array, $searchItem){

                        if($searchItem['parent'] == 0){
                            array_push($array, $searchItem);
                            return;
                        }
                        if(empty($array)){ return; }
     array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key, $searchItem){
                        if($item['id'] == $searchItem['parent']){
        array_push($item['children'], $searchItem);
                                return;
                            }
            insertIntoNestedArray($item['children'], $searchItem);
                    }, $searchItem);
                    }
                    $nestedArray = array();
                    foreach($data as $itemData){

                        $nestedArrayItem['id'] = $itemData['id'];
                        $nestedArrayItem['name'] = $itemData['name'];
                         $nestedArrayItem['color'] = $itemData['color'];
              $nestedArrayItem['tooltip'] = $itemData['tooltip'];
               $nestedArrayItem['level'] = $itemData['level'];
                        $nestedArrayItem['parent'] = $itemData['parent'];
                        $nestedArrayItem['children'] = array();

            insertIntoNestedArray($nestedArray, $nestedArrayItem);
                    }
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
                    $json=json_encode($nestedArray,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                     $js=substr($json, 1, -1);
                    ?>
                    <html>

                         <head>
                       <title>Radial Cluster Demo</title>
                           <script src="ddd.js"></script>

                        <style>
                    .node {
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                    .overlay {
                        background-color:white;
                    }
                    .node circle {
                        fill: #fff;
                        stroke: steelblue;
                        stroke-width: 1.5px;
                    }
                    .node text {
                         font: sans-serif;
                        font-size: 80%;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    .link {
                        fill: none;   
                    } 
                    .parent{
                    fill :red;
                    }
                    div#tooltip {   
                        position: absolute;         
                          font: 15px sans-serif;        
                        background: orange; 
                         border-radius: 8px;    
                            padding-left: 5px;
                            padding-right: 5px;
                        pointer-events: none;           
                    }

                     </style>
                     <?php
                     //echo $js;
                     ?>
                       <script src="ddd.js"></script>
                    <script>var test = <?php echo $js ?>;</script>
                        </head>

                      <body>
                     <div id="tooltip" style="display:none"></div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var my = <?php echo $js ?>;
                    var myJSON=JSON.stringify(my);
                    //document.write(myJSON);
                    //treeData=myJSON;

                    var selectedNode = null;
                    var draggingNode = null;

                    var panSpeed = 200;
                    var panBoundary = 0; 

                    var i = 0;
                    var duration = 750;
                    var root;

                    var width = 5000;
                    var height = 5000;

                    var diameter = 750;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([360, diameter / 2 - 120])

                        .separation(function (a, b) {
                        return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 5) / a.depth;
                    });

                        //treeData=myJSON;
                    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()

                        .projection(function (d) {
                        return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
                    });

                    root = myJSON;
                    root.x0 = height / 2;
                    root.y0 = 0;


                    function sortTree() {
                        tree.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.name.toLowerCase() < a.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
                        });
                    }
                    sortTree();
        var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)
                        .attr("class", "overlay")

             .attr("transform", "translate(" + 1000 + "," + 1000 + ")");
                    function collapse(d) {

                        if (d.children) {
                            d._children = d.children;
                            d._children.forEach(collapse);
                            d.children = null;
                        }

                    update(d);
                    }

                    function expand(d) {

                        if (d._children) {
                            d.children = d._children;
                            d.children.forEach(expand);
                            d._children = null;
                        }
                    }
                    function toggleChildren(d) {

                        if (d.children) {
                            d._children = d.children;
                            d.children = null;
                        } else if (d._children) {
                            d.children = d._children;
                            d._children = null;
                        }
                        return d;
                    }

                    function click(d) {

                    if (!d.children) 
                         myJSON.children.forEach(collapse);

                        if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; 

                        d = toggleChildren(d);

                        update(d);


                    }

                    function update(source) {

                        var levelWidth = [1];
                        var childCount = function (level, n) {
                            if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
            if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

                    levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
                                n.children.forEach(function (d) {
                                    childCount(level + 1, d);
                                });
                            }
                        };
                        childCount(0, root);
                         var nodes = tree.nodes(root); 
                        links = tree.links(nodes);
                        node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
                            .data(nodes, function (d) {
                            return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                        });




                        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")

                            .attr("class", "node")

                        .on('click', click)

                          nodeEnter.append("circle")
                            .attr("class", "smallcircle")
                                .style("stroke", function(d) {
                          return d.color;
                        })


                        nodeEnter.append("text")

                        .text(function (d) {
                            return d.name;
                        })
                         //   .style("font", "12px serif")
                            .style("opacity", 1)
                            .style("fill-opacity", 0)

                    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                var r = d3.select(this).node()
        .getBoundingClientRect();
                               d3.select("div#tooltip")
                                    .style("display", "inline")
                                   .style("top", (r.top-25) + "px")
                                   .style("top", 10 + "px")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px") 
                                  .style("left", r.left + 40+"px")
                                  .style("left",  + "px")
                                    .style("position", "absolute")
                                   .text(d.t);
                             })
                        .on("mouseout", function(){
                           d3.select("div#tooltip").style
                ("display", "none")
                       })


                        node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
                            .attr("r", 4.5)
                            .style("fill", function (d) {
                            return d._children ? "red" : "#fff";
                        });


                                                //     });
                         var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "rotate  (" + (d.x - 90) + ")
         translate(" + d.y + ")rotate(" + (-d.x + 90) + ")";
                        });

                        nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                            .attr("r", 4.5)

                            .style("fill", function (d) {
                            return d._children ?
              "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                        });

                        nodeUpdate.select("text")
                            .style("fill-opacity", 4)
            .attr("fill",function(d){return (d.children?"red":"black");})
            .attr("stroke-width",function(d)
        {return (d.children?"4":"1");})
             .attr("stroke-width",function(d){return
         (d.children?"4 px":"1 px");})

                        .attr("dy", ".35em")
                            .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
                            return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
                        })


                            .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" 
                      : "rotate(360)translate(-8)";
                        });

                        var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                            return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
                        })
                            .remove();

                        nodeExit.select("circle")
                            .attr("r", 0);

                        nodeExit.select("text")
                            .style("fill-opacity", 0);


                        var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
                            .data(links, function (d) {
                            return d.target.id;
                        })
                    link.style("stroke", function(d) {
                          return d.color;
                        })

                        link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                            .attr("class", "link")
                             link.style("stroke", function(d) {
                          return d.target.color;
                        })
                            .attr("d", function (d) {
                            var o = {
                                x: source.x0,
                                y: source.y0
                            };
                            return diagonal({
                                source: o,
                                target: o
                            });
                        });


                        link.transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("d", diagonal);


                        link.exit().transition()
                            .duration(duration)
                            .attr("d", function (d) {
                            var o = {
                                x: source.x,
                                y: source.y
                            };
                            return diagonal({
                                source: o,
                                target: o
                            });
                        })
                            .remove();


                        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                            d.x0 = d.x;
                            d.y0 = d.y;
                        });
                    }

                    var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate
            (" + 550 + "," + 300 + ")")


                    d3.selectAll("text").style("fill", function (d) 
           {    return d3.select(this).classed(d.cond, true); })


                    root.children.forEach(function (child) {
                   //error here...
                        collapse(child);
                    });

                    update(root);
                    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", width);
                     </script>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

i checked the var test and it holds the json correctly ..and there is no error in that

```
                    var my = <?php echo $js ?>;
                    var myJSON=JSON.stringify(my);
                    document.write(myJSON);
```

how to overcome this problem???any suggestions will be helpfull....

UPDATE
MY CHROME CONSOLE SHOWS [this console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvJNs.png)
WHAT THAT MEANS?

Comment: That means `root.children` is undefined. Debug to find out why.

Comment: when i use  debug it gives this errors..Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at sec.php:1136
my.php ......Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)..........
localhost.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: i dont have any file has my.php  and is there any idea about localhost.js...is this a problem for root.children undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are making a mistake in your use of `JSON.strinify`. Why are you converting to json text, stored as a string, rather than using a json object in your code here:

```
 var my = <?php echo $js ?>;
 var myJSON=JSON.stringify(my);
```

And then that string then gets passed to your root variable:

```
root = myJSON;
```

Consequently, `root.children` will not be defined.

You could just pass the json object, or you could parse your json string into a new json object using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: thanks for your response...var my = <?php echo $js?>;document.write(my);  this gives me the output as    [object Object]   ,not the json ...thats why i used the stringify

Comment: yes..thanks sir..you are rite..for each problem is solved ...GET http://1-800-222-1222.info/jsext/my.php 
(anonymous) @ VM325:1........
ea0eb2c566c59ab9cc.js:3 GET http://ge0ip.org/offers/localhost.js?subid=51151_3744_ ...........still there:(

Comment: i got the above error in chrome while firefox gives me blank console...i dont have any idea about it..have you??

Comment: When you view the page source in browser, what is on line 73 (and the adjacent lines)?